# Can we add a node to state object after Map state in step Functions, AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

Let's suppose there is a Step Function with a MAP state that processes an orders and add address to each order,
Input for Map state object:

```
{
   "Id":"djhkjs",
    "Orders":["1","2","3"]
}
```

Map state is for `"Orders"` list, During Map state execution there is a Lambda to append address.

Input State Object for each iteration:

```
Order: "1"
```

Output State Object for each iteration:

```
Order: "1",
Address: "CA"
```

Combined Output after `MAP`:

```
[
  {
    Order: "1",
    Address: "CA"
   }
  {
    Order: "2",
    Address: "CA"
   }
   {
    Order: "3",
    Address: "CA"
   }
]
```

What should i do to get the following output?(Instead of list, a JSON Object with a parameter)

```
{
 [
  {
    Order: "1",
    Address: "CA"
   }
  {
    Order: "2",
    Address: "CA"
   }
   {
    Order: "3",
    Address: "CA"
   }
 ]
ID:"hjshjdhsj",
Name:"Services"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the output of each state in your workflow will be the input of the next state and all previous input will be replaced with the last output.

To change it, use the ResultPath filter to include the original input in the state's output.

**Example**

Workflow Definition:

```
{
  "StartAt": "Map",
  "States": {
    "Map": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "INLINE"
        },
        "StartAt": "Pass",
        "States": {
          "Pass": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "End": true,
            "Result": {
              "Order.$": "$",
              "Address": "Address"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true,
      "ItemsPath": "$.Orders",
      "ResultPath": "$.result"
    }
  }
}
```

Execution input:

```
{"Orders": [1,2,3,4,5]}
```

Output:

```
{
  "Orders": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
  ],
  "result": [
    {
      "Order.$": "$",
      "Address": "Address"
    },
    {
      "Order.$": "$",
      "Address": "Address"
    },
    {
      "Order.$": "$",
      "Address": "Address"
    },
    {
      "Order.$": "$",
      "Address": "Address"
    },
    {
      "Order.$": "$",
      "Address": "Address"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you see in the output, the Map result (the array) is not the root element anymore.

Comment: That seems perfect! What do you think I can do to delete a node from the object?

Comment: @tejaswi, I can think of 2 options to delete node:
1. You can add a pass state with parameter and choose what you want to keep
2. Use States.JsonMerge and override anything you want to delete with empty string "", you can't delete node, but you can mask data in that node

Comment: JSON.merge feels like right solution for me, But How do i update the root object in? Results: ".$": "JSONMerge("")"